# Batch - Ping on Multiple sites

Tags: windows, batch-file, ping

*So I want to ping, 20 different sites 15 consecutive times with the same data size and take their Average RTT into a file. But I must also check the same IP for different sizes of ping data, from 8 to 2048 every time multiplied with 2 (8, 16, 32, 64 etc).*

I tried to develop my own code and here is what I have so far.

```
@echo off
CLS
ping -n 1 %1|find "Reply" > nul
CLS
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 ( FOR %%G IN (8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048) DO (echo Pinging with %%G byte of data... & ping -n 1 -l %%G %1|findstr /x "^.*Request.* ^.*Lost.*  ^.*Average.*ms" >> results.txt)) ELSE (ECHO The Server %1 did not respond)
```

For easier reading:

```
@echo off
CLS
ping -n 1 %1
CLS
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 
( 
    FOR %%G IN (8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048) DO 
    (
        echo Pinging with %%G byte of data... &
        ping -n 15 -l %%G %1|findstr /x "^.*Request.* ^.*Lost.*  ^.*Average.*ms" >> results.txt
) 
ELSE
( ECHO "The Server did not respond" )
```

What I want to accomplish is, a batch file that, accepts 10 (or 15 if it is possible) parameters that are websites ping all of them with 8, 16, 32, ...,  2048 for 15 times each site and also if the server for any reason in some of my ping requests gives me a Request time out, I want to stop the loop for this parameter and continue with the next one but I want it to write to the file that "Request Time Out"

In my code, I am trying to check if the server responds on my ping requests, if I get a reply then begin my FOR loop.

Although, I can't check at any given time if the server still accepts my pings, this happens more often when I have packets of 2048 bytes. If the server give me a "NO" then I get a "Request time out".

So with some kind of code implementation I want to check if the command

```
ping -n 15 -l %%G %1|findstr /x "^.*Request.* ^.*Lost.*  ^.*Average.*ms"
```

will print ***Request Time Out*** so I can stop the ping and move on the next parameter, so it won't bother pinging the same IP 15 times.

Also, with the above implementation I won't have to check at the start of the script if the server responds because it will do it inside the FOR loop.

I believe that the parameter switching is not that hard to implement, it's just a shift and some labels.

Thank you in advance for your time, I will be glad to give you more explanations on the commends below!

Comment: This looks like a batch script, not bash; if so, please correct the title and tags.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry about that...

Comment: The syntax you are using for parentheses is wrong for your IF and FOR commands. Open up a cmd prompt and read the help for each command.

Comment: The batch file runs fine pal... it's the first one not the second, the second code is just for better readability...

Comment: Please don't `find "Reply"`. Think of `Reply from <localhost>: Destination host unreachable`. Better use `find "TTL="`

Comment: @Stephan Oh thanks for pointing, I didn't think about it!!